# HTTP 403 WildFly Application Server

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, wildfly

Eclipse project imported into Netbeans
Import issues:

- Unsupported classpath container found. It will be ignored and you may need to update the NetBeans project classpath by hand.
  The internal name of this container is:
  'org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER'
- An existing NetBeans project was found and will be used istead.

Clean & Build: build success

Run (IE browser):

```
http://localhost:8080/MyServletFilter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
The website declined to show this webpage
HTTP 403
```

WildFly Application Server

I'm wondering:

1. Can the import issues be the reason of the problem I'm complaining about? (HTTP 403 The website declined to show this webpage)
2. "An existing NetBeans project was found and will be used istead." Does that mean the project was not actually an Eclipse project?
   Anyway iy should be an Eclipse project since .project and .classpath files are both in the project folder
3. `The website declined to show this webpage HTTP 403` Is there a solution?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my question? Is that because there's no fix? Maybe I don't deserve an answer...should I post somewhere else? can anyone tell me the reason why I haven't received any reply so far?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a very specific question, since only few people will try to automatically convert an Eclipse project for use in Netbeans. I also never went that path so cannot tell about that issue.

But if you get a 403 it means that Wildfly is running and it also deployed the application successfully (otherwise you would get a `connection refused` or a `404 not found` response in your client). So for some reason Wildfly or the application decided to respond with `403 not authorized`.

Therefore try to check three locations:

1. declarative security in web.xml
2. declarative security in standalone.xml (or whichever other configuration file you may be running)
3. the application code, which may also check authorization and decide to respond with 403

If you believe everything is configured right and still get that response, reconfigure JBoss logging to be extremely verbose and drill down from here.